# Using Sub, that proceses Excel objects, from within Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am using the CreateCSV() public sub within Outlook 15.0 however obtain the error message "Compile Error: User Defined Type Not Defined" at the second line below.

```
Public Sub CreateCSV(dataWbFile As String, Optional InputDt As String)    
Dim dataWb As Workbook
```

For context, I am using CreateCSV within this piece of code:

```
For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
        If LCase(Right(Atmt.filename, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
            filename = DestFolder & Atmt.filename
            Atmt.SaveAsFile filename
            ReceivedTime = DateSerial(Year(Item.ReceivedTime), Month(Item.ReceivedTime), Day(Item.ReceivedTime))
            Call CreateCSV(filename, ReceivedTime)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next Atmt
    Item.Delete
Next Item
```

Which I am using to sort through a file of emails, save the attachments and delete the email after doing so.

I'm new to this. I've downloaded the Tools->References package Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library which I read was one potential problem.

Comment: I'd guess you'd want to include a reference to `Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library` if you want to refer to `Workbook` *from* Outlook.

Comment: Thanks! That did the job.

Answer (score 1):

Include a reference to `Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library` if you want to refer to `Workbook` from Outlook.